Adding top level directory to PYTHONPATH prevents mypy from checking a file
My top level directory /project contains a file /project/caller.py and a subdirectory /project/lib. This directory contains a file /project/lib/callee.py
These files contain:
/project/caller.py:
import  callee

/project/lib/callee.py:
len([]).startswith("42")

After setting export MYPYPATH=/project/lib and unset PYTHONPATH
python -m mypy caller.py

gives the intended result:
lib/callee.py:1: error: "int" has no attribute "startswith"  [attr-defined]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

Whereas when: export MYPYPATH=/project/lib and export PYTHONPATH=/project, no error is found:
Success: no issues found in 1 source file

It looks like adding the top level directory to PYTHONPATH prevented mypy from checking the imported file.
Could someone please explain me why?
(Python 3.12.0, mypy 1.10.0)
